# I want to add label or text as shown in image below using swift

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

After clicking on some buttons, the title of button should appear as label or text with 'X' mark, after clicking on 'X' the text should disappear from search bar.

Comment: then why you add objective-c tag ?

Answer (score 0):

Hoefull this will help you.

```
let tagsField = WSTagsField()
tagsField.backgroundColor = .white
tagsField.padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
tagsField.spaceBetweenTags = 10.0
tagsField.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 12.0)
tagsField.tintColor = .green
tagsField.textColor = .black
tagsField.fieldTextColor = .blue
tagsField.selectedColor = .black
tagsField.selectedTextColor = .red
tagsField.delimiter = ","

// Events
tagsField.onDidAddTag = { _ in
    print("DidAddTag")
}

tagsField.onDidRemoveTag = { _ in
    print("DidRemoveTag")
}

tagsField.onDidChangeText = { _, text in
    print("DidChangeText")
}

tagsField.onDidBeginEditing = { _ in
    print("DidBeginEditing")
}

tagsField.onDidEndEditing = { _ in
    print("DidEndEditing")
}

tagsField.onDidChangeHeightTo = { sender, height in
    print("HeightTo \(height)")
}
```

https://github.com/whitesmith/WSTagsField/blob/master/README.md